# springboot 2.0.5 integration websocket error

Tags: java, spring, websocket

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaSMb.png)

[image]

console error:

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
>   11:36:58 spring-boot [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to register @ServerEndpoint class: class com.simple.springbootbasic.basic.websocket.WebSocketServer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$50508009
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoint(ServerEndpointExporter.java:158)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoints(ServerEndpointExporter.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(ServerEndpointExporter.java:111)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>       at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265)
>       at com.simple.springbootbasic.Application.main(Application.java:19)
>   Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Cannot deploy POJO class [com.simple.springbootbasic.basic.websocket.WebSocketServer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$50508009] as it is not annotated with @ServerEndpoint
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.addEndpoint(WsServerContainer.java:203)
>       at org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServerEndpointExporter.registerEndpoint(ServerEndpointExporter.java:155)
>       ... 12 common frames omitted
>   11:36:58 spring-boot [main] INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@72ea6193: startup date [Thu Sep 20 11:36:53 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   11:36:58 spring-boot [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
>   11:36:58 spring-boot [main] INFO  c.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidDataSource - {dataSource-1} closed
>   Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:2440', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Please provide us more information to your problem. How does your code look like and what are you trying to achive?

Comment: We need some code, but If You read the exception carefully:

"Cannot deploy POJO class [com.simple.springbootbasic.basic.websocket.WebSocketServer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$50508009] as it is not annotated with @ServerEndpoint"

Sooo, did You annotate your class?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your project contains, but I have gotten the same error in my own project when I had two classes that are both annotated `@ServerEndpoint`. There should only be one endpoint per project, so if your project contains two classes that are both annotated `@ServerEndpoint`, simply remove the `@ServerEndpoint` annotation from one of the classes.